# Call a stored procedure in multi scalar table-valued function?

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

Is there any way to call a stored procedure in **multi scalar table-valued function** like that?

Note: this query returns error:

> *Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.*

T-SQL code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnCrSum
(
@ay nvarchar(100), @yil nvarchar(4), @tip nvarchar(25)
)
RETURNS 
@tablo TABLE 
(
    id int,
    ref_num int,
    last_name nvarchar(200),
    grup nvarchar(200),
    analist nvarchar(200),
    durum nvarchar(10),
    start_dt int , 
    end_dt int,
    duration int,
    type nvarchar(10),
    bildirim nvarchar(200)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @exec NVARCHAR(250)
    SET @exec = 'exec dbo.spCrSum ''' + @ay + ''', ''' + @yil + ''', ''' +  @tip + ''''
    INSERT INTO @tablo
    exec (@exec)

    RETURN 
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Functions can't have side effects i.e. change data.

Even if your stored procedure doesn't change anything, the SQL compiler can't assume that, So it just doesn't allow it.

Why do you need to wrap this in a function?

Comment: Because, there are technical problems on Business Objects Designer side.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute a stored procedure in a function.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem. I wrote a table-valued function including executable query, returns table and prepared an stored procedure to call that function passing parameters. It works for me.