# Is it possible to call a stored procedure in a user defined function ?

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

Is it possible to call a stored procedure in a user defined function in sql server, mysql or oracle  ?

Comment: In SQL Server: no, you cannot call stored procedures from inside functions.

Comment: Maybe, that comment helps you.

[Call a stored procedure in multi scalar table-valued function][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860233/1671361

Comment: I think you can call some system Extended Stored Proc (xp_something) but I don't think you can with your own Stored Proc (except using openquery "hack" as pointed out by Dave Hilditch)

Answer (score 1):

You can cheat and [call the stored procedure from within a function using SQL Server](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread8955-how-can-call-stored-procedure-inside-function-in-sql-server-2005.aspx) using extended stored procs or openquery.

Normally, you want your function to be deterministic - i.e. given the same dataset it always returns the same results. See this [Microsoft article on deterministic and non-deterministic functions to understand the restrictions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx)

It depends on what you want to do with it. There's a healthy chance you want to do something inside your function that you shouldn't be trying to do, because you've come from a procedural or non-set-based programming background.